# URL Rewrite same host different port in IIS 8.5

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I have a server with three websites:

- Default website, port 80 (no content)
- Website A, port 81
- Website B, port 82

I would like to use URL Rewrite to access Website A and Website B like:

http://myserver/A
http://myserver/B

instead of

http://myserver:81
http://myserver:82

I have installed the `URL Rewrite` and `Application Request Routing` modules and enabled the proxy for ARR.

On the default website I created two rewrite rules using the regex pattern `/A/(.*)` and `/B/(.*)`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WebsiteA" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="/A/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:81/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WebsiteB" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="/B/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:82/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Using the `Test pattern...` functionality I could verify that `{R:0}` contained the entire test URL and `{R:1}` just the part after `A/` or `B/`. The *rewrite URL* I sat to point to either port 81 or 82. I still regard *regular expressions* as pure magic but the test gave me what I wanted. Trying to connect to the websites through `/A/` and `/B/` gave me 404 errors.

Seeing that this is a very common problem with lots of questions and answers I picked one suggesting to use the regex pattern `^A(.*)$`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WebsiteA" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^A(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:81/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WebsiteB" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^B(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:82/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Using the test functionality my test URLs failed to match that pattern, but when I tried to access the sites using the new pattern, it worked.

**Question:** I am going with the later solution but is it pure luck that it works and should I perhaps do something different?

Is it normal for the test functionality to not successfully match the same URL's that works when I feed them to the server?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules If you don't want to reveal the actual rules you use, then you have to debug on your own. I have a relevant but not exact matched article on ARR here, https://blog.lextudio.com/wildcard-host-name-support-in-old-iis-releases-8e4448040b5a

Comment: @Lex Li, I have updated my question to show the actual rewrite rules.